# tokenization from textfield/textarea

Tags: java, textarea, tokenize

i want to do tokenize from textarea but i cannot call the textarea. the output cannot diplay.

Below is my program:

```
static JTextArea Report_tf;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
      {
      new Form1(); //call form

//tokenization

  String speech = Report_tf.getText();
  Report_tf.setText(speech);

  StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(speech);
  while (st.hasMoreTokens()) 
    System.out.println(st.nextToken());
}
```

Comment: Please describe your issues/errors in more detail.

Comment: i cannot call the input to token..tq

Comment: i'm problem here: String speech = Report_tf.getText();
  Report_tf.setText(speech);

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get a compile-time exception? A run-time error? Post that.

Comment: there is no error in my program.. but the output don't display. because i don't know to call textArea to use as a input..

Comment: Have you read any of my answer below?

Answer (score 2):

Is that what your code looks like, or is it facsimile of your code? I see a few problems in that small snippet:

- There's no reason to have a static JtextArea field as this breaks OOP. Make it an instance variable of the class (I guess it's the Form1 class).
- Where do you construct your JTextArea variable? As written it appears to be null and will throw a NullPointerException if you try to use it.
- If you're trying to extract your text from the JTextArea from the main method as you indicate, you're doing this **at program start up, before the user has had any time to enter data into the JTextArea** which makes little sense. Much better is to get the text in response to an event such as inside of a JButton's ActionListener. This way, the user can enter text and then push the button when done, and your field will have text to extract.
- Again, all of this should be not be done in the main or any static method but in a non-static method.

If this information doesn't help, you'll need to provide more information than you have, a lot more information and code.